# Ground cherries have dirt on them

Tags: cherries

Have ground cherry plants.  Cherries are coming out yellow but have black dirt? on them and in the husk?  Not sure what this is and it cherry is still editable?

Comment: This is one occasion where we really do need a photograph or two...